# Problem with install security patch in magento 2.2.7

Tags: composer-php, magento2

I want to install a patch to my project

Patch like this:

```
Index: vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php   (revision 6a8701ca9402697f5eaf022e35b9217d3281546c)
+++ vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php   (date 1553502112000)
@@ -2904,7 +2904,7 @@
                 if (isset($condition['to'])) {
                     $query .= empty($query) ? '' : ' AND ';
                     $to     = $this->_prepareSqlDateCondition($condition, 'to');
-                    $query = $this->_prepareQuotedSqlCondition($query . $conditionKeyMap['to'], $to, $fieldName);
+                    $query = $query . $this->_prepareQuotedSqlCondition($conditionKeyMap['to'], $to, $fieldName);
                 }
             } elseif (array_key_exists($key, $conditionKeyMap)) {
                 $value = $condition[$key];
```

I also added to the composer:

```
"extra": {
        "magento-force": "override",
        "patches": {
            "magento/framework": {
                "Fix: PRODSECBUG-2198":
                "patches/composer/magento/framework/PRODSECBUG2198.patch"
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to run composer install then return this error:
*Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch patches/composer/magento/framework/PRODSECBUG2198.patch*

Project for Magento 2.2.7, I installed cweagans/composer-patches but still have problem. Someone can help?

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have too much experience with the patches package, but in one of our project, we use it too. In the patch file, the location to the files to be patched is given relative to the package root. So, if you want to patch something in `magento/framework`, your patch file should probably use `DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` as the filenames